# I need to access information in my smartphone's memory. The screen is completely dead and does not respond to touches or show any image

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen, ram

I need to access information in my smartphone's memory. The screen is completely dead and does not respond to touches or show any image. The computer does not detect the smartphone, it only charges.

Is there a way to access the smartphone's memory without changing the touchscreen? I do not want to spend a lot of money on this.

Comment: Not really. ADB can be used in this cases but that depends on having previously enabled such access. You may try booting in recovery mode that for some phones exposes the userspace via USB but that's a long shot.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. By "memory", did you mean "file storage", or literally "RAM"?

Comment: what phone model? what rom/android version? bootloader unlocked?